# How to write SQL query where the columns of the result set are computed from the source data table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table (#t_timevalue) similar to the next example:

```
Time    Value
-------------
t1        v1
t1        v2
t1        v3
t2        v1
t2        v3
t3        v1
t4        v2
t4        v3
```

I'm trying to create a query to summarize the data as follows:

```
Time  v1   v2   v3
t1    1    1    1
t2    1    0    1
t3    1    0    0
t4    0    1    1

where (ti,vj) = 1 if record (ti,vj) record appeared in #t_timevalue
      (ti,vj) = 0 elsewhere
```

Is it possible to produce such output using SQL?

**or at least the targeted summary information:**

```
1    1    1
1    0    1
1    0    0
0    1    1
```

**Edit**

The column `Value` contains unknown values, and their count seems to be huge. 
Is the recommended solution to push this report up to be manipulated by the application layer, not the database one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select time,
       max(case when value = 'v1' then 1 else 0 end) as v1,
       max(case when value = 'v2' then 1 else 0 end) as v2,
       max(case when value = 'v3' then 1 else 0 end) as v3
from t
group by time
order by time;
```

EDIT:

You can do this using a dynamic pivot -- if you don't have too many values (there is a limit on the number of columns in a SQL Server table or result set):

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @cols = stuff((select distinct ', max(case when value = ''' + @value + ''' then 1 else 0 end) as ' + quotename(value) 
                      from t
                      for xml path (''), type
                     ).value( '.' , 'nvarchar(max)'
                            ), 1, 1, ''
                    ) ;

select @sql = '
select time, ' + @cols + '
from t
group by time';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Actually, I can't know the values (v1, v2, v3,...), they are data, so I can't hard code them. On the other hand, the values' count seems to be huge and not known.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I've tested it, it works perfectly when the values count is rather small (below 4095 ), with big number of values I get the following error message:
`The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.`
which explains itself.

Comment: @Lio . . . As I say . . . "if you don't have too many values".

Comment: yes, it's clear and works in such case, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The pivot operator also works for you.

```
create table testrr
(
[Time] varchar(30),
[Value] varchar(30)
)

insert into testrr values
('t1','v1'),
('t1','v2'),
('t1','v3'),
('t2','v1'),
('t2','v3'),
('t3','v1'),
('t4','v2'),
('t4','v3')

SELECT 
[Time],[v1],[v2],[v3]
FROM
(
SELECT 
[Time],[Value],1 AS NUMBER
FROM testrr
) SRC
PIVOT
(
 count(NUMBER) FOR [Value] IN ([v1],[v2],[v3])
) pvt

--Output
/*
Time                           v1          v2          v3
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
t1                             1           1           1
t2                             1           0           1
t3                             1           0           0
t4                             0           1           1
*/
```

Best Regards,

Will

Comment: Thank you Will, but as I commented to @Gordon 's answer, values (v1, v2, v3,...) are not known exactly, they are data, hard coding them is not feasible.

Comment: I know your thought, this also could be applied to dynamic SQL